# Subdomain redirecting to main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, dreamhost

I have a domain `farragutanchor.com`, with the two subdomains of `lockers.farragutanchor.com` and `hallpass.farragutanchor.com`. Each domain has its own directory, and each directory with its own files and `.htaccess` file. And yet for some reason, attempting to log on to either subdomain redirects me to the main site. The `.htaccess` file is included below, and I can include php code as well, although all of it has work fine under a different subdomain.

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex lockers.php
```

I use DreamHost as my hosting platform, and an agent assured me nothing on their end was causing a redirect. In previous testing, everything has worked under a different subdomain, except `lockers.farragutanchor.com` was `test.farragutanchor.com/lockers`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the PHP with redirects bouncing around several files before landing on the home page.